# java.io.FileNotFoundException on local databricks directory but directory exists

Tags: databricks, dbutils

I am trying to copy a directory in databricks from one location to another

```
dbutils.fs.cp("/path/to/directory", "new_path/to/directory")
```

Prior to running this I confirm the directory exists:

```
folders <- list.folders("/path/to/", full.names = TRUE) 
print(folders)
```

I receive this error despite /path/to/directory being confirmed as existing:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the schema, then it's assumed `dbfs:`, while you're trying to copy local file to DBFS. You need to specify `file:` schema when working with local files:

To copy local file to DBFS:

```
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/path/to/directory", "new_path/to/directory")
```

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity - the directory for copy is in dbfs and the destination is also dbfs

Comment: isn't `list.folders("/path/to/"` for local files?

Comment: Thanks for this Alex, you're right. I assumed I was working exclusively in dbfs but it turns out when I used the file: and/or dbfs: schemas I could find and move things as expected!